# How to create a new table by matching & joining two different columns from the original table

Tags: pyspark

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Series_Name | Comparable_Series_Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 10000       | AAAAA                  | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| AAAAA       | NULL                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 20000       | BBBBB                  | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| BBBBB       | NULL                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 30000       | CCCCC                  | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| CCCCC       | NULL                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| DDDDD       | NULL                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| EEEEE       | NULL                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 40000       | NULL                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 50000       | NULL                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

This is a master table that contains all the data of two series (series of workflows).

- The series with numerical name (e.g. 10000) is the main series, and the series with alphabetic name (e.g. AAAAA) is the minor series.
- Not all main series has a matching minor series (vice versa).
- As you can see, there is a problem with this data: when `Series_Name` is a major series, it tells you what the comparable minor series name is (if any), but when `Series_Name` is a minor series, it gives you a comparable series name of `NULL`.

I am trying to create a table out of this master table that is solely dedicated to **minor series**, so it would look something like this:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Series_Name | Comparable_Major_Series | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| AAAAA       | 10000                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| BBBBB       | 20000                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| CCCCC       | 30000                   | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| DDDDD       | NULL                    | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| EEEEE       | NULL                    | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I am doing this in PySpark.

I am thinking to do something like this:

```
tbl_tmp = tbl.select("Series_Name", "Comparable_Series_Name")

tbl_minor = tbl.where(F.col("Comparable_Series_Name").isNull()).join(tbl_tmp, on = ???, how = 'left')
```

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl_tmp = tbl.selectExpr("Series_Name AS Comparable_Series_Name", "Comparable_Series_Name AS Series_Name")

tbl_minor = tbl.filter("Series_Name not rlike '\\\\d+'").drop('Comparable_Series_Name').join(tbl_tmp, ["Series_Name"], "left")

tbl_minor.sort("Series_Name").show(10, False)
# +-----------+------+------+------+----------------------+
# |Series_Name|Value1|Value2|Value3|Comparable_Series_Name|
# +-----------+------+------+------+----------------------+
# |AAAAA      |xxx   |xxx   |xxx   |10000                 |
# |BBBBB      |xxx   |xxx   |xxx   |20000                 |
# |CCCCC      |xxx   |xxx   |xxx   |30000                 |
# |DDDDD      |xxx   |xxx   |xxx   |null                  |
# |EEEEE      |xxx   |xxx   |xxx   |null                  |
# +-----------+------+------+------+----------------------+
```